# Inherited class function takes more inputs than base class

Tags: c++

I have functions that I need to apply to different domains on 3 different variables (`x`, `y`, `z`).  Normally each functions takes only one of the variables as inputs.  For example:

```
float myFunction(float val) { return val * 3.14159; }
```

These functions can be simple constant multiplication, interpolation, derivatives, etc.  I want to have a `vector` that contains functions which are defined over different domains.  For example all `x` functions are in `std::vector<…> xFunctions`, `std::vector<…> yFunctions`, etc.

Now I need to add the ability of a function to take all three variables as inputs but I want to keep them in `vector`s.

Here is an example

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Model {
public:
  Model(float b1 = 0.0, float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
      : lowerBound(b1), upperBound(b2) {}

  virtual float Function(float inp) { return 0.0; }

  float GetUpperBound() const { return upperBound; }

  float GetLowerBound() const { return lowerBound; }

protected:
  float lowerBound, upperBound;
};

class ConstantModel : public Model {
public:
  ConstantModel(float b1 = 0.0,
                float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(),
                float f = 0.0)
      : Model(b1, b2), factor(f) {}

  float Function(float inp) { return factor; }

private:
  float factor;
};

class LinearModel : public Model {
private:
  float interpFactor1, interpFactor2;
  float interpTerm;

public:
  LinearModel(float b1 = 0.0, float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(),
              float f1 = 0.0, float f2 = 0.0)
      : Model(b1, b2), interpFactor1(f1), interpFactor2(f2) {
    interpTerm = (interpFactor1 - interpFactor1) / (upperBound - lowerBound);
  }

  float Function(float inp) {
    return interpFactor1 + (inp - lowerBound) * interpTerm;
  }
};

class MultipleInputs : public Model {
private:
  float factor;

public:
  MultipleInputs(float b1 = 0.0,
                 float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(),
                 float f1 = 0.0)
      : Model(b1, b2), factor(f1) {}

  float Function(float inpX, float inpY, float inpZ) {
    return factor * (inpX + inpY + inpZ);
  }
};

int main() {
  // In practice I have xModels, yModels, zModels
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Model>> xModels;

  xModels.emplace_back(new ConstantModel(0.0, 1.0, 3.14159));
  xModels.emplace_back(new LinearModel(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0));
  xModels.emplace_back(new MultipleInputs(3.0, 4.0, -1.0));

  float xValue;
  float yValue(1.0), zValue(2.0);
  std::cin >> xValue;

  // Find the applicable function to use
  std::size_t i = 0;
  while (xModels[i]->GetUpperBound() < xValue) {
    ++i;
  }
  float result = xModels[i]->Function(xValue);
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  ;

  return 0;
}
```

If I input `0.5` the result is `3.14159`.  If I enter `1.5` the result is `1`.  If I enter `3.5` I want the answer to be `(3.5 + 1.0 + 2.0) * -1.0 = -6.5`.  However, I get `0` because the function `Model::Function` is called.  This makes perfect sense because I only give 1 input.  If I give 3 inputs I get the expected compiler error "function does not take 3 arguments".

I started down the path of using `decltype` and run-time type identification, but this makes me think I am just doing this wrong.  What is the proper way to have an inherited class member function take more inputs than the base class?

**Update**

I modified the base class to have an overloaded `Function(float, float, float)` and then used `typeid.hash_code()` to determine if I needed to use the 1 or 3 input function like this.

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Model {
public:
    Model(float b1 = 0.0, float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) :
        lowerBound(b1), upperBound(b2) {}
    virtual float Function(float inp) { return 0.0; }
    virtual float Function(float i1, float i2, float i3) { return 0.0; }
    float GetUpperBound() const { return upperBound; }
    float GetLowerBound() const { return lowerBound; }

protected:
    float lowerBound, upperBound;
};

class ConstantModel : public Model {
public:
    ConstantModel(float b1 = 0.0, float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(), float f = 0.0) :
        Model(b1, b2), factor(f) {}
        float Function(float inp) { return factor; }

private:
    float factor;
};

class LinearModel : public Model {

private:
    float interpFactor1, interpFactor2;
    float interpTerm;

public:
    LinearModel(float b1 = 0.0, float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(), float f1 = 0.0, float f2 = 0.0) :
        Model(b1, b2), interpFactor1(f1), interpFactor2(f2) {
        interpTerm = (interpFactor1 - interpFactor1) / (upperBound - lowerBound);
    }
    float Function(float inp) { return interpFactor1 + (inp - lowerBound) * interpTerm; }
};

class MultipleInputs : public Model {

private:
    float factor;

public:
    MultipleInputs(float b1 = 0.0, float b2 = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(), float f1 = 0.0) :
        Model(b1, b2), factor(f1) {}
    float Function(float inpX, float inpY, float inpZ) { return factor * (inpX + inpY + inpZ); }
};

int main() {

    // In practice I have xModels, yModels, zModels
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Model> > xModels;
    std::vector<std::size_t> tags;
    tags.emplace_back(typeid(Model).hash_code());
    tags.emplace_back(typeid(ConstantModel).hash_code());
    tags.emplace_back(typeid(LinearModel).hash_code());
    tags.emplace_back(typeid(MultipleInputs).hash_code());

    for (auto i : tags) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    xModels.emplace_back(new ConstantModel(0.0, 1.0, 3.14159));
    xModels.emplace_back(new LinearModel(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0));
    xModels.emplace_back(new MultipleInputs(3.0, 4.0, -1.0));

    float xValue;
    float yValue(1.0), zValue(2.0);
    std::cin >> xValue;

    // Find the applicable function to use
    std::size_t i = 0;
    while (xModels[i]->GetUpperBound() < xValue) {
        ++i;
    }
    float result;
    if (typeid(*xModels[i]).hash_code() == tags[3]) {
        result = xModels[i]->Function(xValue, yValue, zValue);
    }
    else {
        float result = xModels[i]->Function(xValue);
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

This works in the sense that I get the 3 input version when I want it, but it feels like there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Usually we call this overload function. since they have the same name, they are still different functions for compiler.

Comment: Side note, you might find[`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) of use to you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way to have an inherited class member function take more inputs than the base class?

A virtual function cannot be redefined with a different signature, and derived classes must implement all virtual function according to the base class' specification. If you cannot ensure this, your design is problematic and you want to revise it.

A derived class can define a new, unrelated function, in addition to the original inherited function. If the signatures are different, both functions may have the same name, resulting in function overloading.

Comment: Can you please review my update and comment?  I think you're right that the design is problematic.

Comment: @Matt The new design is problematic too. Whenever you need to use typeid to select the right functionality, there is a good chance that you are doing it wrong. At the very least you can have a virtual function like "needsThreeArguments" (you should probably invent a meaningful name for it).

Comment: I think I got an acceptable solution.  I changed the functions to take `const std::array<float, 3>&, std::size_t>` as inputs.  This allows them all to have the same signature.  The ones that need a certain value get that through the `size_t` and the one that needs all three just ignores it.  Thanks for looking.